# tabs not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have a page that I am using javascript to change content when you click on different tabs.  It works perfectly on desktop but it's not working on mobile.

Here's the site - http://pt6-dev.info/donate-now/

Here is my Javascript -

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it


window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
};
```

I really appreciate any help!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the square. It is an anchor tag. Actually, there is no difference between desktop and mobile because clicking on the square reloads the page. I don't see why it's there as an anchor tag. You can just make it a `<div>` and put `cursor: pointer;` on it.